# JAVA: get String value from Class1 and call to the other Class2

Tags: java

I'm trying to get that name string from LoginForm to MainForm so I may now the user who logged in with their name. My problem is that, I cant pass the retrieved name from database in LoginForm class to MainForm.

Why is that if I perform this code;

```
public class LoginForm extends JFrame{
    ...
    .
    public LoginForm(){
       ...
       .
       MainForm thisoh = new MainForm();
       thisoh.getthisnow(rs.getString("Given_Name"));
       ...
       .
    }
}
```

and then, in the other class;

```
public class MainForm extends JFrame {
   private String fname;
       String getthisnow(String usrname) {
          this.fname = usrname;
          return fname;
          }
       public MainForm() {
          initComponents();
          txt_HomeWelcome.setText(fname);//JLabel
          ...
          .
       }
}
```

The `JLabel` become `null`.. :-( It suppose to show the name from the LoginForm, right? Did I miss something?? Please help! >.< I need that `fname` from LoginForm. That's my problem.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Does: rs.getString("Given_Name"); give an error or something? Or what do you mean?

Comment: If you're trying to set the label to be `Jlabel.setText(user)` on the new `MainForm()`, shouldn't you assign a variable to the `MainForm`? `myForm = new MainForm()`, myForm.setVisible(true), then `myForm.setText(user)`?

Comment: If "Given_Name" is column name, yes you can. And actually that is how you read a resultSet object. [Here is](http://stackoverflow.com/a/187425/381897) a more detailed answer. But, if you try to filter by user name using result set, I do not think it is possible. Also please be more clear about what you are trying to achieve and what is the error your are getting.

Comment: When you say "System" do you mean like Windows? Or your own solution?

Comment: @matrixanomaly
no errors at all... its a String user declared. but inside the LoginForm, the "user" is called by JOption to message window to welcome the user and specify its name, and that is "Given_Name" from database...

Comment: @bhdrkn ok thank you, but i'll seek my own with you guys so I may develop my skills in programming.. I'm an student studying this kind of program.

Comment: @CarefreeCrayon Oops! my bad, I'm sorry... the "System" I am talking about is the MainForm... I'm sorry for my terms. LoLz

Comment: @DraganBozanovic I'm making a LoginForm that whoever logged in the MainForm will be recognize by itself(MainForm). is that even possible?

Comment: You already have everything you need. The result of the SQL query has the user name, just pass it to the main form.

new MainForm(rs.getString("Given_name")).setVisible(true);

Comment: @CarefreeCrayon okay? and then I got this MainForm(String string) {
    }

Comment: see my answer for more details

Comment: sir @CarefreeCrayon I got an error! it says "java.lang.NullPointerException"

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do here is pass your username to your Main form and set the value to a label somewhere.

```
new MainForm(rs.getString("Given_name")).setVisible(true);
```

then in MainForm

```
public class MainForm extends JFrame {
    private String username;
    public MainForm(String username){
        this.username = username;

        //you set the value of your label to username
        // here or somewhere else in your form
         mLabel.setText(username);
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an error in this line:
new MainForm(rs.getStrin("Given_name")).setVisible(true);

Comment: Fixed typo. Should be getString

Comment: yes, I recognize it... but still error... I think the resultSet thing... I manage to make another ResultSet but still error... ugh*!

Comment: Make sure that Given_name is a column in your database which is not null and is spelled exactly the same way you pass it in getString( ). If it still doesn't work. It indicates a problem in your SQL query rather than your Swing logic

Comment: I added your answer for a result of it... please see. thanks!

Comment: should I have to create another public MainForm() for this function? since I got the default one.

Comment: See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html
You can have one, the other or more based on your needs