# Why this mysql find max value stament won't run in Java JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a table with column id, i want to select max value of id and +1 to that value because i'm running a loop. But the sql stament not work, but why? i have test it with mysql comand and it work well! Thank you!

> Error: Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Before start
>   of result set at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:959) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:862) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:790) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2469) at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2580) at
>   MyPackage.TestMax.main(TestMax.java:23)
>   C:\Users\lam\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
>
> ### > The second error when try to define my_max_val: Exception in thread
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Before start of
>   result set    at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:959)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:862)     at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkRowPos(ResultSetImpl.java:790)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2469)  at
>   com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2580)  at
>   MyPackage.TestMax.main(TestMax.java:23)
>   C:\Users\lam\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.1\executor-snippets\run.xml:53:
>   Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","user","pass");
        Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
        ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(ID) FROM table");
        int i = myRs.getInt("MAX(ID)")+1;
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

### The second code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","user","pass");
    Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
    ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(ID) as my_max_val FROM table");
    int i = myRs.getInt("my_max_val")+1;
    System.out.println(i);

}
```

Comment: What does "not work?"  What is the error message?

Comment: i have update my question with new error

Comment: @Iam: It's good that you put the new error message.  But so that it makes sense for those reading, make sure you put your new code that goes with it as well.  Otherwise, it's confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define a name for the max value, so, that it will understand which output you want, as below, plus, move the iterator of the result set:

```
    Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database","user","pass");
    Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();
    ResultSet myRs = myStmt.executeQuery("SELECT MAX(ID) as my_max_val FROM table");

    myRs.next(); //you might also have forgotten this
    int i = myRs.getInt("my_max_val")+1;
    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: I have tried it, it's not working!

Comment: Is it the same exception? Don't forget to do ```myRs.next();```

Comment: OP may not have noticed that you added ` as my_max_val` to the query.

Comment: @lamvuong Did you try the updated code? There was a space i didn't notice

Comment: I have deleted that space

Comment: Thank, the problem is i forgot while (myRs.next()) {}. Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to define a name for `max value` if you simply use an columnIndex to retrieve the value

e.g.

```
 int i = myRs.getInt(1)+1;
 System.out.println(i);
```

columnIndex - the first column is 1, the second is 2, ...

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int)

See also

[ResultSet: Retrieving column values by index versus retrieving by label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186799/resultset-retrieving-column-values-by-index-versus-retrieving-by-label)

for the benefit of retrieving by `Label` though.