# NullPointerException when using String from SQL database

Tags: java, sql, database, string, nullpointerexception

I am trying to use a String read from a row in an SQL database, but when I do, I get the following NullPointerException :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ReadCol.data(ReadCol.java:37)
    at ReadCol.main(ReadCol.java:50)
```

My code is shown below...

```
public String[] array;    
ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from ATTENDANCE");

while(rs.next()){
    File file = new File("E:\\eclipse\\workspace\\AutoAttendanceSystem\\res\\AttendanceData.csv");
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file.toPath(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    for (String line : lines) {
        array = line.split(",");
        // This is line 37 :
        if(rs.getString(1).equals(array[0]) && rs.getString(7).equals(array[6])){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Can't Update Because record already exist");
        }
    }
```

Here is the SQL table's structure :

```
CREATE TABLE "ATTENDANCE" ( 
   "ATTENDANT_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
   "ATTENDANT_AGE" NUMBER, 
   "ATTENDANT_CONTACT_NO" NUMBER, 
   "ATTENDANT_DEPARTMENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
   "REGISTRATION_NUM" VARCHAR2(50), 
   "ABSENT_PRESENT" VARCHAR2(4000) DEFAULT 'Absent', 
   "ATTENDANCE_TIME_DATE" VARCHAR2(4000) 
)
```

And here is an example of a row in that table :

```
Sun 2016.08.14 at 11:21:43 PM PDT, null, null, Thu 2016.08.18 at 01:58:34 AM PDT, null, Thu 2016.08.18 at 02:13:26 AM PDT, null
```

What is the problem ?

Comment: When is a string equal to an array?! An array of what?

Comment: What is `rs` and what is `array` could you show us all the code?

Comment: Please post your best [mcve] attempt.

Comment: Sorry... I've updated the code now..

Comment: @Mee Please provide a [mcve], and pay extra attention to ‘*complete*’ and ‘*verifiable*’.

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew it is not doing the comparison and not showing the Message Dialog... Except that it is showing the exception..

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew This is how I created the Table
`CREATE TABLE  "ATTENDANCE" 
   ( "ATTENDANT_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
 "ATTENDANT_AGE" NUMBER, 
 "ATTENDANT_CONTACT_NO" NUMBER, 
 "ATTENDANT_DEPARTMENT_NAME" VARCHAR2(4000), 
 "REGISTRATION_NUM" VARCHAR2(50), 
 "ABSENT_PRESENT" VARCHAR2(4000) DEFAULT 'Absent', 
 "ATTENDANCE_TIME_DATE" VARCHAR2(4000)
   )`

Comment: this is line 37
`if(rs.getString(1).equals(array[0]) && rs.getString(7).equals(array[6])){`

Comment: u guys just banned my "Ask Question" Option.. I found stack overflow very much helpful but because of u guys I am not able to ask any question now    :(

Comment: @VicSeedoubleyew It's still neither complete nor verifiable, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is going on

It appears that the problem is when you call `rs.getString(7).equals(...)` or `rs.getString(1).equals` : this means that `getString` has returned `null`.

This can happen for 2 reasons :

1. The column that you ask (in that case column 1 or 7) doesn't exist

   - (doesn't seem to be the case here given your SQL table structure)
2. a NULL value must have been stored in the column, and `getString` returns `null`, which is why calling `equals` on `null` throws an exception.

Readings about this :

- Information about `ResultSet.getString`'s return value: [ResultSet's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html).
- [Why calling a method on a reference that points to `null` throws a NullPointerException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it/218510#218510)

#### How to solve the problem

First off, to know which column is causing the problem, separate the conditions on 2 lines and see which one throws an exception :

```
if(rs.getString(1).equals(array[0]) && 
   rs.getString(7).equals(array[6])){
```

If it is ok for your database to hold NULL values, then what you should do, is test for it before applying `equals` :

```
if( ( rs.getString(1) == null && array[0] == null
    || rs.getString(1) != null && rs.getString(1).equals(array[0]) )
    && ... // same for 7th column
```

#### Side notes

1. [You should refer to columns using their names rather their index.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/187425/2873507)
2. To make the code easier to understand, you could store the strings you want to compare in variables, and only later test the conditions on these variables.

#### End result

```
String databaseResult1, databaseResult2, fileResult1, fileResult2;


// Start looping
// ...

   databaseResult1 = rs.getString("ATTENDANT_NAME");
   fileResult1 = array[0];
   databaseResult2 = rs.getString("ATTENDANCE_TIME_DATE");
   fileResult2 = array[6];

   if(
       ( databaseResult1 == null && fileResult1 == null 
         || databaseResult1 != null && databaseResult1.equals(fileResult1) )
       &&
       ( databaseResult2 == null && fileResult2 == null 
         || databaseResult2 != null && databaseResult2.equals(fileResult2) )
      ...
```

Comment: In array[6] data is like this 
 `Sun 2016.08.14 at 11:21:43 PM PDT

 null

 null

 Thu 2016.08.18 at 01:58:34 AM PDT

 null
 Thu 2016.08.18 at 02:13:26 AM PDT`
it contains `null` also.... Is exception occurring because of this `null`?

Comment: You are welcome. I added some details on how to make the code easier to understand